# telegram webhook not working with database data

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot

i created a telegram bot. But instead of hard coding the replies, i decide to pull them from database.. below.. the problem is the bot does not return the data i pull from data base. it returns null in telegram.. but if i echo the variable 
`$mes['message']` 
in my browser it returns the valid data. what might be the problem?

```
 $message1 = $db->prepare("SELECT message FROM about where id=1 ");
    $message1->execute();
    $mes = $message1->fetch();
    if (isset($message['text'])) {
        // incoming text message
        $text = $message['text'];

        if ((strpos($text, "/start") === 0) || (strpos($text, "/start") === 0) ) {
            apiRequestJson("sendMessage", array('chat_id' => $chat_id, "text" => 'Hello', 'reply_markup' => array(
                'keyboard' => array(array('Hello', 'Hi')),
                'one_time_keyboard' => true,
                'resize_keyboard' => true)));
        } else if ($text === "Hello" || $text === "Hi") {
            apiRequest("sendMessage", array('chat_id' => $chat_id, "text" => 'Nice to meet you'));
        } else if (strpos($text, "/stop") === 0) {
            apiRequestJson("sendMessage", array('chat_id' => $chat_id, "text" => 'Did i do anything wrong?', 'reply_markup' => array(
                'keyboard' => array(array('Yes', 'No')),
                'one_time_keyboard' => true,
                'resize_keyboard' => true)));
        }else if ($text === "No") {
            apiRequest("sendMessage", array('chat_id' => $chat_id, "text" => 'Nice to meet you'));
        }else if ($text === "Tell me more") {
            apiRequest("sendMessage", array('chat_id' => $chat_id, "text" => '<?php echo $mes2["message"];?>'));
        } else {
            apiRequestWebhook("sendMessage", array('chat_id' => $chat_id, "reply_to_message_id" => $message_id, "text" => '<?php echo $mes1["message"]; ?>'));
        }


    } else {
        apiRequestJson("sendMessage", ['chat_id' => $chat_id, "text" => $me2 , 'reply_markup' => [
            'keyboard' => [['Tell me more', 'Got it']],
            'one_time_keyboard' => true,
            'resize_keyboard' => true]]);
    }
```

Comment: You try to use `$mes1["message"]` but I don't see where `$mes1` is defined. Maybe you meant `$mes["message"]` ?

Comment: First make sure the fetched data from database is not null.

Comment: yes i meant `$mes["message"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out the problem.
the database object `$text` was not available in  the function holding the if statements.
i had to declare it as global in the function.
e.g

```
    function sendMessage () {
    global $text;
    //if statements here
    }
```

it works fine now

Answer (score 0):

You don't need use **<php echo** for params in functions.

Look at you other variables like $chat_id, $me2... You should use *"text" => $mes1["message"]* and *"text" => $mes2["message"]*

it's already proccessed by PHP. You don't need to embed it one more time

```
     }else if ($text === "Tell me more") {
        apiRequest("sendMessage", array('chat_id' => $chat_id, "text" => $mes2["message"]));
    } else {
        apiRequestWebhook("sendMessage", array('chat_id' => $chat_id, "reply_to_message_id" => $message_id, "text" => $mes1["message"]));
    }
```